# How to get heart rate from fitbit charge HR used BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, fitbit

I purchased a heart rate Fitbit Charge HR and now I want to implement an app get information heart rate. I tried to read the sensor through this example that uses bluetooth low energy (Link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).
I was able to connect to devices but do not get the information to measure heart rate. I have refer https://dev.fitbit.com for API for the same and generate consumer key and consumer secret. But it seems it is for web application only.
I want FitBit android bluetooth API so I get data from fitbit to android apps over Bluetooth. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Charge HR has no support for rebroadcasting the HR over the standard BTLE profile so you want be able to collect the data that way live.  Your only chance is if they have a private API but I would be surprised if they have this for live data.  Recorded data yes but live data no.  Its the 'Can re-broadcast Heart Rate data' line your interested in in the DC Rainmaker product comparison chart.  http://www.dcrainmaker.com/2015/02/fitbit-charge-review.html

The live rebroadcast feature is rare but there are some devices that do it, more ANT+ though than BTLE.